# Multiprovider with some changeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to understand better how MultiProviders works, but I'm experiencing something that is not clear. this is my code starting from the main.dart. within main I have

```
runApp(
  MyApp(),
);
```

where MyApp is a stateless widget that return my main screen.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static final APLogger log = LoggerFactory.instance("MyApp");
  // This widget is the root of your application.

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MultiProvider(
       builder: (context, child) => child!,
       providers: [
         ChangeNotifierProvider<APPUserService>(
           create: (context) => APPUserService.instance,
         ),
         ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
           create: (context) => AuthService.instance,
         ),
         ChangeNotifierProvider<SubscriptionNotifier>(
           create: (context) => SubscriptionNotifier(),
         ),
       ],
       child: materialApp(context, flexScheme),
     );
   }
```

APPUserService, AuthService, SubscriptionNotifier are classes that extends ChangeNotifier and I logged at the begin of the constructor a string to catch when they are instantiated.
the issue is that only the AuthService is logged during the initialisation
could you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

below the singleton defined for example for APPUserService

```
  static APPUserService? _instance;
  static APPUserService get instance {
    log('APPUserService == start == instance');
    _instance ??= APPUserService._();
    return _instance!;
  }
```

Comment: If you're maintaining legacy code, package:provider is still useful, but a lot of these complications are streamlined in package:riverpod, which is recommended now by the author as the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing might be related to the lazy instantiation of your singleton instance in the ChangeNotifierProvider.

The ChangeNotifierProvider creates the instance of the provided class when it is first accessed.

If the instance is not accessed within the build context of the MyApp widget, the constructor won't be called.

Comment: good point. I've noticed that the singleton is instanciated at first use later.